# How to program query in SearchModel for boolean attribute combined with or

Tags: yii2

Following query will select all records of database, where attribute arbeitsumfang_vollzeit is true:

```
if ($this->DropDown_Arbeitszeit == 1) {
 $query = Bewerber::find()->where(['arbeitsumfang_vollzeit' => true]);
}
```

Following query **should** select all records, where attribute arbeitsumfang_vollzeit or arbeitsumfang_terilzeit is true, but I fail with it.

```
if ($this->DropDown_Arbeitszeit == 2) {
            $query = Bewerber::find()->andFilterWhere(['or',
                ['=', 'arbeitsumfang_vollzeit', $this->arbeitsumfang_vollzeit],
                ['=', 'arbeitsumfang_teilzeit', $this->arbeitsumfang_teilzeit]]);
}
```

How to code query correctly?

Comment: what is the output if you add `->createCommand()->rawSql;` at the end of the query ? `andFilterWhere` will omit the condition from the query, if the parameter is empty or `null`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that you might have `$this->arbeitsumfang_vollzeit` as `null` not `false` which would result in not filtering the query as you wish,

Answer (score 0):

From your description I would guess that you need something like this:

```
if ($this->DropDown_Arbeitszeit == 2) {
    $query = Bewerber::find()->andWhere([
        'or',
        ['=', 'arbeitsumfang_vollzeit', 1],
        ['=', 'arbeitsumfang_teilzeit', 1],
    ]);
}
```